# Ubuntu wont boot after install from usb

Tags: boot, system-installation, usb

I have installed ubuntu 16.04.1 lts from a usb.  There were no errors reported during the install.  However when I restart and leave the usb in I only have options to try ubuntu or install.  If I remove the usb it reports that I have no bootable media.  Any ideas what I am doing wrong.  My lap top is a Acer Aspire E5-573.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: You may reinstall the OS! Normally errors during an installation are really bad. Otherwise you could try to install `grub` inside a `chroot` environment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

BIOS settings:

- use standard boot, not UEFI
- set your Ubuntu HDD first the boot device list.

If still not booting, most probably you don't have a bootloader installed on the MBR of your Ubuntu HDD (maybe the wrong device was selected during GRUB setup ?).

No need to do a full reinstall here, boot a linux system (rescue CD or other PC), and go :

```
$ sudo grub-install /dev/sda
```

(adapt /dev/sda to your HDD letter)

Comment: Changing from UFEI boot was the answer.  Thank you.

Comment: glad you made it ~ would you mind validating the answer ?